# Checking the return value of a custom templatetag in a template

Tags: django, templatetags

I have created a custom template tag which does some processing and returns 1, if all goes well,0 if not.
In my template I want to check the returned value, and if it is 1, display an image. How should I go about doing this?

The name of my function is fname which takes an argument n, and return a value of 1 or 0.
So, I want to check

```
{% if fname n %}
   <img src="">
{% endif %}
```

my custom templatetag called testing.py

```
def fname(name):
    path = 'media/'
    path += name

    if path != "media/":
        x_test = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread(path), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        x_test = np.array(x_test)/127.5 - 1.
        x_test = x_test.reshape((1, 256, 256, 3)) #1 since keras expects first element of shape to be reserved for batch size
        gen = generator.predict(x_test)
        scipy.misc.imsave("main/static/main/modimages/"+name, gen[0])
        return 1

    else:
        return 0
```

in my template

```
{% load testing %}
{% if fname n %}
<img src="abc.jpg">
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This doesn't make any sense to do in a template tag. Why are you doing this? You're creating files and saving them, why would you do this in a template tag?

Comment: for django, you cannot call function directly in template.

Answer (score 0):

```
def index(request):
    name = 'yourpic.jpg'
    context= {
        'fname': fname(name)
        }
    return render(request, 'yourpage.html', context)
```

in template

```
{% if fname == 1 %}
<img src="abc.jpg">
{% endif %}
```